# Alternative to redraw_timer()

Tags: python, scripting

I have a script whose goal is to find all the visible vertices from the camera view. The simplest solution should work as follows:

1. Go Into Camera View
2. Update the view with `bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN_SWAP', iterations=1)`
3. Get the coordinates of [the borders of the camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6377/coordinates-of-corners-of-camera-view-border) and use `bpy.ops.view3d.select_border()`

However, the redraw_timer() function is giving me the following error

```
WM: failed to allocate texture for triple buffer drawing (glGenTextures).
wmSubWindowScissorSet 0: doesn't exist
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Now, I'm not surprised. The [Gotchas](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_0/info_gotcha.html?highlight=redraw_timer#can-i-redraw-during-the-script) mentions that this could be expected.

How should I then replace redraw_timer()?

I have tried `bpy.context.scene.update()`, `bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()` and [a modal operator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28673/update-viewport-while-running-script) with no success. How should I then proceed?

**IMPORTANT UPDATE** (02.11.2015)

Both answers (zeffii and batFINGER) select all vertices in the camera frustrum. This means that vertices behind others are selected. This is not what I'm looking for. I need the **unobstructed and visible** vertices. That's why I thought of using `bpy.ops.view3d.select_border()` in camera perspective. Here is an example.

If Suzanne is seen by the camera like this
[image: Suzanne watched through a camera.]

I want the following vertices selected.
[image: Two images are shown of Suzanne in EDIT mode. The selected vertices are only the ones that are seen through the camera lens and unobstructed by others vertices.]

I apologize for making my issue unclear.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-find-image-coordinates-of-the-rendered-vertex

Comment: Thanks for adding a bit more specificity to your question, perhaps I'll remove my answer until I have time to modify it.

Comment: you might need to be more specific when iterating over views... https://gist.github.com/zeffii/a01cbb28aed399146a86  this might be it.. if the error is that you are trying to set the border in a window area like the N panel of 3dview..

Comment: By the by, there is another way to do it. It's called back-face culling. Here is an answer that details how to do it. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-find-back-faces-and-delete-them-with-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**IMPORTANT EDIT**

re question change, pretty much the same code added to a modal timer operator, and changed to use view3d.border_select.  Run the operator in 3dview, then when in edit mode Right click in camera view to select vertices.   Set`space.use_occlude_geometry` to view **unobstructed and visible** vertices.

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import location_3d_to_region_2d

def view3d_find():
    # returns first 3d view, normally we get from context
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]
            rv3d = v3d.region_3d
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    return region, rv3d
    return None, None

def view3d_camera_border(scene):
    obj = scene.camera
    cam = obj.data

    frame = cam.view_frame(scene)

    # move into object space
    frame = [obj.matrix_world * v for v in frame]

    # move into pixelspace

    region, rv3d = view3d_find()
    frame_px = [location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d, v) for v in frame]
    return frame_px

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "BXXX"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        scene = context.scene
        obj = context.object
        region = context.area.regions[-1]

        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE'}:
            print("modal")
            if obj.mode == 'EDIT' and obj.type == 'MESH':
                camframe = view3d_camera_border(scene)

                #print([xy for xy in camframe])

                bpy.ops.view3d.select_border(gesture_mode=3, xmin=camframe[2].x, xmax=camframe[0].x,
                                             ymin=camframe[1].y, ymax=camframe[0].y)

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Similar to the method used in https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40264/15543 , the handler below selects only the verts in the camera view, and deselects the rest, live, in edit mode.

Uses `view3d_camera_border(...)` and `view3d_find` methods from https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14746/15543

```
dic = {}
@persistent
def edit_object_change_handler(scene):
    # if not some.prop return
    obj = scene.objects.active
    if obj is None:
        return None

    if obj.mode == 'EDIT' and obj.type == 'MESH':
        camframe = view3d_camera_border(scene)
        region, rv3d = view3d_find()
        #print([xy for xy in camframe])
        bm = dic.setdefault(obj.name, bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data))

        for v in bm.verts:
            xy = location_3d_to_region_2d(region, rv3d,
                                          obj.matrix_world * v.co)
            v.select = ((camframe[2].x <= xy.x <= camframe[0].x) 
                    and (camframe[1].y <= xy.y <= camframe[0].y))
            #print(v.select, v)            
        return None

    for bm in dic.values():
        bm.free()

    dic.clear()
    return None
```

[image: Cam view select verts]

Cannot see why same would not work in a modal(timer).  Needs some property flag to turn it on or off.

I'd be tempted to extend the BMesh

Comment: Nice answer. But the context to bpy.ops.view3d.select_border(gesture_mode=3, xmin=camframe[2].x, xmax=camframe[0].x, ymin=camframe[1].y, ymax=camframe[0].y) is incorrect. [More details here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31374/18475)

Comment: Yep, quite aware of overriding  context when running outside the view3d area. I used the name BXXX to make it quick to find in the spacebar menu for testing purposes.

Comment: @TedMilker Have a look at `bpy.ops.view3d.select_box(...)`