# How to find if the vertex of an object is occluded by another vertex/face in front of it from a given viewpoint?

Tags: rendering, camera, coordinates

I can use the recipes on this page: [How to find image coordinates of the rendered vertex?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/882/how-to-find-image-coordinates-of-the-rendered-vertex). But is there a way to know if a point is being occluded by some point/face in front of it from the viewpoint of a given camera in the scene?

Comment: Have you tried removing doubles? Press W and select remove doubles, and if there are two vertices in exactly the same place it will dissolve one of them. Outside of that I'm not sure what you mean. Can you upload a picture?

Comment: I want to find the image coordinates of every 3d point on an object that is visible to the camera. Some points on an object will not be visible due to occlusion. But if I use the recipe provided in the link above, it gives the image coordinates of all points irrespective of the fact whether they are visible to the camera or not. A point might not be visible if there is another face of the object in front of it that obstructs its view.

Comment: You could use Blender's "limit selection to visible" feature. If you change the view to camera, and turn on "limit to visible selection" (the little cube with white vertices) in edit mode, you can select all of the points you can see while leaving the ones you can't see unselected. You can then go into the Select menu (lower left) and choose Inverse. Now all of the points you *can't* see will be selected, and you can just separate them or delete them or whatever you like so they won't read as points. Would that work?

Comment: Sounds like something that would be helpful. However, I am interacting only through the Python interface. I'll look for a way to do that through Python scripting. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: One hack that comes to mind in say I have N 3D points all mapped to the same coordinate in the image is I find the distance between the 3D point and camera coordinates and only consider the closest point as visible.

Comment: Script to do similar http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40823/alternative-to-redraw-timer/40826?s=2|0.1053#40826.  Would be the  difference of the verts selected with and without occlude_geometry.