# How to select only visible vertices using python API?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

I'd like to select only the visible vertices (from the camera), using python interface.

I use `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.use_occlude_geometry = True` to limit the selection, but when it is followed by `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')`, it results in all mesh vertices being selected and not only the visible ones.

I probably don't understand how to use the `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.use_occlude_geometry` or the selection operator correctly - will appreciate your help with it.

Anastasia

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40826/15543

Comment: Thanks, @batFINGER, it's related but I need to do everything via Python API. Is there any way to replace the manual vertex selection by a set of python commands? Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

First of all, as for the `select_all` behavior, that is by design.
Calling `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')` is the same thing as pressing the <kbd>A</kbd> key, which selects *ALL* items, even ones outside of the view frustum, even ones occluded and not visible.

To select visible vertices in python similar to border or circle select honoring `bpy.types.SpaceView3D.use_occlude_geometry` and `bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode`:

```
import bpy

def getView3dAreaAndRegion(context):
  for area in context.screen.areas:
      if area.type == "VIEW_3D":
        for region in area.regions:
          if region.type == "WINDOW":
            return area, region

def select_border(context, view3dAreaAndRegion=None, extend=True):
  if not view3dAreaAndRegion:
    view3dAreaAndRegion = getView3dAreaAndRegion(context)
  view3dArea, view3dRegion = view3dAreaAndRegion
  override = context.copy()
  override['area'] = view3dArea
  override['region'] = view3dRegion
  bpy.ops.view3d.select_border(override,
                               gesture_mode=3,
                               xmin=0,
                               xmax=view3dArea.width,
                               ymin=0,
                               ymax=view3dArea.height,
                               extend=extend)
  return view3dAreaAndRegion
```

Then to use this, just add after the function definitions:

```
select_border(bpy.context)
```

**Blender >2.8**

```
def getView3dAreaAndRegion(context):
  for area in context.screen.areas: 
      if area.type == "VIEW_3D":    
        for region in area.regions:
          if region.type == "WINDOW":
            print("Found WINDOW") 
            return area, region

def select_border(context, view3dAreaAndRegion=None, extend=True):
  if not view3dAreaAndRegion:
    view3dAreaAndRegion = getView3dAreaAndRegion(context)
    print(view3dAreaAndRegion)
  view3dArea, view3dRegion = view3dAreaAndRegion
  override = context.copy()
  override['area'] = view3dArea
  override['region'] = view3dRegion
  bpy.ops.view3d.select_box(override,xmin=0,xmax=view3dArea.width,ymin=0,ymax=view3dArea.height,mode='ADD')
```

and then, with a selected object in Edit mode, run

```
select_border(bpy.context)
```

**Very important:** This code needs to be run in a window that has a 3D Editor view in it. So if you're running the code editor in a separate detached window, it won't work !

Comment: Uh...why the downvote, sirs?

Comment: Dunno who downvoted, but it worked nicely when I tested it.