# Selecting vertices in headless mode

Tags: scripting, selection-tools

So I have a little script that selects all visible vertices by going to the camera view, entering edit mode and then calling `bpy.ops.view3d.select_box`. I now want to move to headless mode to run my script on a server, but from what I gathered, it's not possible to use `select_box` in headless mode.

Are there any workarounds for this? I couldn't find anything useful, so I'm afraid it will be a rather time-intensive and ugly solution...

PS: A "headless" tag might be useful

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64318/how-to-select-only-visible-vertices-using-python-api

Comment: @XY Yeah I am doing pretty much that, but the script fails due to a segmentation fault when run in headless mode

Comment: Maybe bmesh method work,   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40823/alternative-to-redraw-timer/40826#40826

Comment: This did the trick! Needed some time to integrate it with the other stuff in my script, but it works now! I'll post a minimal script example as the answer later on - thanks!