# List all objects that appear in the camera FOV (avoid occluded objects)

Tags: python

Is there a way to list/print all objects in camera FOV that not occluded objects?
prefer without iterating all verts like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40823/alternative-to-redraw-timer/40826#40826)

```
        for obj in bpy.data.objects:
            if obj.type == 'MESH':
                 # detect object appear in camera view (not occluded by other object) 
                 # also visible_get() is not the function i need
```

Comment: You would need to calculate the viewing frustum of the camera; determine what objects are in it by comparing at least bounding boxes; and then figure out which are behind others.  If you want any sort of accuracy you would need to calculate based on the vertices in at least some cases.

Comment: @MartyFouts thanks for that!