# how to find back faces with python

Tags: python, modeling, topology

How to find faces pointing inward with a python script which uses Blender sdk?

AN example:

[image]

Normally I trigger "backface culling" and select points/face by visual inspection:

[image]

Then I delete the selected geometry, which leaves a hole:

[image]

And finally I do a F-fill:

[image]

In short, I'm asking if there's a way to select backfaces without a visual check, using python. There's an answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/938/how-to-find-back-faces-and-delete-them-with-python) by Zeffii, but it is related to a camera view, while I'm looking for something topology-related...
Thank you.

EDIT: how I did it.

[get the blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1COM-HIOO2PWAk4B1l9dX1GXuUC3vH5cW)

Open the blend, and select the partial sphere:

[image]

Now enter select edges, the Select non manifold (ctlr-alt-shift-M), then F or Alt-F for filling it. The result is:

[image]

How to heal that?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72647/select-object-and-recalculate-normals-via-script

Comment: Thank you. Sadly recalculating normal has no effect; that face is legitimate, just lies over another one, extruding out into a bad topology...

Comment: If the problem is not backfacing, you need to logically break down the problem with topology you want to fix before you can find a way to programmatically detect the cases. The geometry is non-manifold, you have edges that only connect to 1 face. Is this what you want to find?

Comment: I posted some more info. It's not clear to me, I think it's creating overlapping faces with different orientation...